# (error) not a valid identifier of IP number on terminal ubuntu

Tags: terminal, ip

When I run  my terminal it works fine. But In the top of the active line, i get the following warning.

```
bash: export: `192.168.1.17': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `192.168.55.1': not a valid identifier                              
bash: export: `172.17.0.1': not a valid identifier
```

how do I solve and get rid of it?

thanks

Comment: Do you use the IPs as variable names? Show the offending code lines.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some issue with exporting a variable.
I would suggest you wrap the IP  in double quotes as shown below.

`export ip="192.168.1.17"`

If you can share the script it would be easy to answer.